# How to add a DOUBLE outline to a text or a shape in Adobe Illustrator ?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, text, stroke

I am creating a logo and I would like to put a double outline on it, do you know any clever way to do it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Edit: There was a better way to do Quick & Dirty #1.  I have revised the answer with the improvement.  This is now my preferred method.*

Like many Illustrator things, there are multiple ways to do this.

**The Quick & Dirty Ways**

Use these methods if the outline object is at the bottom of your layer stack and transparency doesn't matter.

*Quick & Dirty #1* **(Recommended)**

1. Select your object and on the `Appearance` palette select the Menu and `Add new stroke`
2. Select the new stroke on the `Appearance` palette and go to menu `Effect` ⇒ `Path` ⇒ `Offset Path` and offset it by a point or 2.
3. (Optional) If you want to reuse this style, open the `Graphic Styles` Palette and select the Menu and choose `New Graphic Style...`

*Quick & Dirty #2*

1. Copy & Paste duplicates of your object above each other until you have 3 identical objects.
2. Make the lowest-layered object have a thick stroke.
3. Make the middle-layered object have a less-thick stroke in a different color.
4. Make the the top-layered object have the thinnest stroke.

If you really need transparency, you can select your objects and `Outline Stroke` to form filled shapes.  Then subtract & combine your shapes as appropriate to quickly create an outlined solid-fill shape object.

*The "Brush" Way*

This method is very flexible but takes more time to set up.  <strike>This is definitely the method you want to use if you will be using this border style in multiple places.</strike>

1. Make a `Art Brush`

   1. Create multiple parallel lines (I find it easiest to start with horizontal lines)
   2. Select your lines
   3. Open your Brushes palette (F5).
   4. Click the menu and select `New Brush...`
   5. Choose New Art Brush
   6. Make sure the direction guide arrow is going the correct direction for your lines.
2. Apply your new `Brush` to the object that you want outlined

   1. Select your object.
   2. Click on your newly created brush on the `Brushes` palette.

Creating your own brush is simple and powerful for basic shapes like lines or easy curves.  If your object has many corners you will need to edit your brush to include the correct way to form corners.

*Edit:* Afterthought.  If you're making a complex shape that needs outlines, you're going to need to create a `Pattern Brush` to accommodate corners, you can't do this with an `Art Brush`.  To create a `Pattern Brush`, you need to create each of your corner & side situations and then create pattern swatches.  You then use the pattern swatches to create your `Pattern Brush`.

---

Here's the easiest way I know of to make your pattern brush:

1. Make tiles for each of the required tiles (Outer Corner, Inner Corner, Start, Side, End).
   Keep in mind that the tiles need to align with each other on shapes so it may help to create squares and build your tiles in the squares.  In the below image, I made my bounding squares blue so you can see them.  When I use them to create swatches in the next step I will remove the stroke from the squares.

   [image: Example tiles for pattern brush]
2. Drag each of your tiles up to your `Swatches` palette to make pattern swatches.

   [image: Pattern swatches in my palette]
3. Make a new pattern brush and assign your swatches to each of the appropriate tiles.
   You may need to adjust your scaling if you made your pattern at a much larger size than its intended use case.
   (Note also that the end-tile indicator is misleading.  The End tile should be pointed the same direction as your start tile, as if they were the same object.  The dialog seems to indicate that it should be faced the opposite direction but this is incorrect.)

   [image: Pattern brush options]
4. Apply your pattern to shapes to test it out.

   [image: Pattern brush applied to shapes]
5. When you apply it to a font, you may need to clean up the anchors a bit where they are too close together (depending on the scale of your pattern).  For example:

   - Here's a B from Font to Outlines with no cleanup (using my example brush stroke):

   [image: B with too many points]

   - Here's the same B with an extraneous point removed:

   [image: B with extra point cleaned up]

Comment: I tried the "Correct way", but its kind of buggy cause I can't seem to be able to get the corners right. First I tried with the Art Brush and it doesnt work on all corners, then I tried with the Pattern Brush and again, it definetly doesn't work on all corners, have a look at my result : 

http://flavius.clickgarden.net/multipleStrokes.jpg                                                 How would you make your Pattern Brush to get it to make the corners right for that complex shape?

Comment: @Flavius - Pattern Brush is the right one but it's tricky to make it right.  The easiest way is to create a grid of squares and use it to partition your corners.  I'll post images when I get a chance.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for your answer cause I don't know how to use the Pattern Brush thingy at all...never used it before. THX

Comment: farray simlpy rocks

Comment: @Jack Farray has too much free time on his hands.  ;)

Comment: that's good you getting all  knowledge

Comment: @Farray Thank you very much for the tutorial thingy, a lot of work on your side to try and explain it to me, i tried and got some kind of result, not the double outline(plus I needed each of the outlines to have a diffrent color, and its gets even more complicated that way) but some more weird looking thing around my text, it looks interesting, great for other projects, as for the logo I was working at...I think the best solution when it comes to text(for me) remains the Strokes in the Appearence panel, and if I need to use transparency I just expand the stroke and thats it.

Answer (score 5):

How I do it:

Create your text. Clone it three times. You now have your text layered 3 times.

Bottom layer gets a border of, say, 10pt black. Next gets 8pt white. Next gets 6pt black. Top layer gets no border at all.

But I'm old fashioned. Farray's solution is probably good too. Just be sure that you don't distort the letterforms with a stroke that goes inside glyph.

Answer (score 4):

Simply apply additional strokes to the text via the **Appearance Panel** and use `Effect > Path > Offset Path` to move the strokes away from the characters.

[image]

If you then want the strokes to be independent objects, choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do it, I think. In the Appearances panel, after you've selected the path, just click on fx and add another stroke, or two if you like. You'll have to fiddle with the settings to get it to sit beside your previous stroke rather than on or inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to add multiple concentric strokes around an object in Illustrator:

1. Apply a stroke in the Appearance panel, and make sure that stroke is selected (the stroke, not the whole object)
2. Go to Effect > Path > Offset Path...  This will apply the effect to the stroke. When you add the effect, you can set the offset in the dialog.
3. Add another stroke in the Appearance panel, then apply the effect again. This time, set the offset to be whatever increment you want as spacing between the concentric strokes. You can quickly apply the effect to each stroke with the shortcut Shift + Cmd + E (on Mac)
4. Repeat for each concentric stroke, as many as you want. Each time, set the offset to be another multiple of the increment you want as spacing between strokes (for example, 10, 20, 30, 40). You could also have uneven spacing between strokes if you want.
5. Each of the strokes is individually editable, as is the spacing between them, and they will follow the contours of the underlying shape, leaving it editable. You can also save this appearance as a graphic style and apply it easily to other shapes.